¿La carpeta .gitlab debe estar en el tracking del seguimiento de git o debe agregarse al .gitignore?

La carpeta .gitlab debe estar en el tracking del seguimiento de git o debe agregarse al .gitignore? No estoy preguntando si debe eliminarse del disco. Mi pregunta es si .git debe darle seguimiento o no ¿Qué es lo recomendable y por qué?
